# Can Aluminium Chlorohydrate in anti prespirants cause breast cancer?

Tags: cancer, hygiene, chemical

I read an online article about Aluminium being linked to breast cancer. So I did a little research and found some articles claiming there is no solid evidence.

Sources-

www.m.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/features/antiperspirant-facts-safety

https://www.truthinaging.com/review/what-is-it-aluminum-in-deodorant-and-is-it-dangerous

www.skintelligencenter.vmvhypoallergenics.com

Comment: Hi there, welcome to health.SE! Could you please share the sources you read with us?

Comment: 1.skintelligencenter.vmvhypoallergenics.com/c39-skin-health/mythfoliation2isaluminumdangerous/    www.m.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/features/antiperspirant-facts-safety

Comment: 'linked' but, not causing. The link was maybe a coincidence and based on the fact that parabens were found in the breast tissue of individuals with breast cancer. Not enough research has been done into parabens and their role in cancer, yet, so not many will be able to help you. The fact that parabens are in situ anyway is a cause for concern, yes. Be careful what you read on the Internet ;)